# How to reference a cell `itself` when conditional formating a range through custom formulas?

Tags: google-sheets, gs-conditional-formatting

#### Situation so far

On a spreadsheet, a range of dates are calculated. The passed dates should be colored in red and the future ones in green. This is done by these `custom formula`:

```
red if Less or equals than =now()
green if Greater than =now()
```

Why not use `Date is before` or `Date is after`? Because theses options only test the **day** and not the whole **date** (including hours and minutes and seconds.

#### Actual objective

Now I want to color in orange the close dates, date that are about `now + 2 hours`. The formula `hour(A1)` returns the hour the cell *A1*.

---

#### Question

My question is, in the field `Custom formula` how to use the function `hour(cell)` (or any other) to the cell itself? In other words, how to point the actual cell the test is being performed on?

Answer (score 0):

Try this formula:

```
=and($A1<=(now()+2/24),$A1>=now())
```

`2/24` means two hours.

`$A1` means leave only column 1, `$` before `A` freezes column. I assumed that your dates are in range `A1:A`. Change this formula for yor range with dates.

Comment: What is this `$A1` notation?

Answer (score -1):

The right way to performed the needed test is to use the `Less than [or equal to]` instead of the `Custom formula` with the field filled with `=(now()+(0.5/24))` to color date that are half an hour in the future.